# Why printing the first member of structure by using the structure tag name and using %d specifier for character member result in strange output?

Tags: c

Consider this code

```
struct node1 {
   int i;
} node2;

node2.i = 56;
printf("%d", node2); // This will print 56
```

But now if we change int with char like this

```
struct node1 {
       char i;
    } node2;
    
    node2.i = 'A';
    printf("%d", node2); // This will print 32577
```

My question is why the output here is not ASCII value of A which 65?

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf`. `%d` format specifier excepts `int`, not structures. Obtaining detailed reasons of this specific results will require detailed investigation of your environments: for example, the compilation result (assembly code).

Comment: This use is allowed it just need to look at the code from hardware level perspective then you will be able to see the reason behind the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first member of the `struct` and the `struct` itself shares the same address, in the first case the correct value is printed because all bytes from `addressof(node1)` to `adressof(node1) + sizeof(int)` are filled and matches with the specifier `%d` --> `int`, usually 4 bytes.

```
struct node1 {
[byte 1] 56 -> if little endian, otherwise it is set in byte 4
[byte 2] 0
[byte 3] 0
[byte 4] 0
[byte 5] garbage
[byte 6] garbage
...
```

in the second case, where size of `char` is 1:

```
struct node1 {
[byte 1] 'A'
[byte 2] garbage
[byte 3] garbage
[byte 4] garbage
[byte 5] garbage
[byte 6] garbage
...
```

Since `printf("%d", ...)` reads 4 bytes, you get garbage.

At this point you may be wondering, why this pece of code:

```
char c = 'A';
printf("%d\n", c);
```

doesn't print garbage and work as expected?

Because variadic functions (and `printf` is) promotes arguments of type `char` (and also `short`) to `int`, it also promotes `float` to `double` (that's why you can use `%f` with both types), but in the case of  your `struct` there is not such automatic promotion, you need to use a cast:

```
struct node
{
    char c;
    ...
} node1;

node1.c = 'A';
printf("%c\n", *(char *)&node1);
```

Comment: OP's snippet is not passing any address to `printf()`

Comment: @pmg and what does that have to do with my answer? `printf("%d"` reads 4 bytes, regardless of what we pass to it. I use the `addresof` word to state that the bytes starts at this offset.

Comment: @DavidRanieri That is a beautiful explanation. It requires hardware level understanding of the language.

Comment: @AdwaitUpadhyay oh thanks, well ... my knowledge is very limited but I am glad to have helped you :)

Comment: @AdwaitUpadhyay There is no need for hardware level understanding. It is basically sufficient to know that there are no default conversion rules for structs as there are for integer values. And as soon as you provide a value that does not match the type defined by the format specifier, everything is possible.